# cfform target iframe page missing

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, coldfusion

I have a form that submitted by javascript via a button click. It was an ajax submit to an iframe. Everything was working fine until I changed the tag from 'form' to 'cfform'. From what I understand, this shouldn't cause a problem, but, obviously, I am mistaken. I need cfform because I want to use a cftextarea with the richtext attribute. With the tag as cfform, upon a submit the iframe displays a 404 which completely boggles my mind. Here is my code.

coldfusion:

```
//In my code, the lines are not broken like this
<cfform action="<cfif IsDefined('URL.itemID')>
    actionEditItem.cfm
<cfelse>
    actionAddItem.cfm</cfif>"
method="post" target="my_iframe" name="itemForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

//the button that submits the form, again, lines aren't broken
<input type="button" <cfif IsDefined('URL.itemID')>
    value='Update Item' onClick='javascript:updateItem();'
<cfelse>
    value='Add Item' onClick='javascript:validateItem();'
</cfif>>
```

javascript:

```
    itemForm.submit();
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Using `cfform` adds a lot of javascript to your page and I assume that is conflicting with your javascript code.  Just view the source of your page when using `cfform` versus using just a regular `form` and you will see what I am talking about.  Possibly can find the issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a CFIF inside the `cfform` tag like you are doing. It's trying to render the `cfform` and breaking. This is not an issue with a regular html form. For this instance, I would set a temp var and use that within the `action` attribute.

```
<cfif structkeyexists(url,"itemID")>
    <cfset formAction = "actionEditItem.cfm">
<cfelse>
    <cfset formAction = "actionAddItem.cfm">
</cfif>
<cfform action="#formAction#" method="post" target="my_iframe" name="itemForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a temp var, you can use `IIF`.

```
<cfform action="#iif(structkeyexists(url,'itemID'),de('actionEditItem.cfm'),de('actionAddItem.cfm'))#">
```

Comment: iif is kinda slow so I'd use the variable, you may be able to use it in other places too once it is set. If you're using CF9 or 10 you can use the ternary operator, action = "#structKeyExists(url,'itemID')?'actionEditItem.cfm':'actionAddItem.cfm'#"

Comment: To elaborate on phantom42's answer, you CAN put the cfif inside your action attribute (that's why it doesn't error) **but it does not evaluate.** Once you view your source the HTML would look something like <form action = "<cfif isDefined('URL.itemID')>actionEditItem.cfm<cfelse>actionAddItem.cfm</cfif>" method="post" target="my_iframe" name="itemForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">